# Grabbing data from previous year in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got this df:

```
d={'year':[2019,2018,2017],'B':[10,5,17]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df):

   year   B
0  2019  10
1  2018   5
2  2017  17
```

I want to create a column "B_previous_year" that grabs B data from the previous year, in a way it looks like this:

```
   year   B   B_previous_year
0  2019  10                 5
1  2018   5                17
2  2017  17               NaN
```

I'm trying this:

```
df['B_previous_year']=df.B.loc[df.year == (df.year - 1)]
```

However my `B_previous_year` is getting full of `NaN`

```
   year   B  B_previous_year
0  2019  10              NaN
1  2018   5              NaN
2  2017  17              NaN
```

How could I do that?

Comment: assuming your frame is sorted and there are no dups just use shift: `df['new_col'] = df['B'].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you want to keep in Integer format:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df['New'] = df.B.shift(-1)
df
```

Output:

```
    year    B   New
0   2019    10  5
1   2018    5   17
2   2017    17  <NA>
```

Comment: I used your shift solution, but used sort_values by year and shift +1. Could you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to sort the dataframe by year first, then verify that the difference from one row to the next is, indeed, one year:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='year')
df['B_previous_year'] = df[df.year.diff() == 1]['B']
```

```
    year    B   B_previous_year
2   2017    17  NaN     
1   2018    5   5.0     
0   2019    10  10.0
```